# How can I set zoom in my profile image when mouse hover

Tags: support, profile-picture, user-card

Often, I saw someone's profile picture and some profile details showed in a popup when I moved my mouse over that profile image.

For example, see the image below.

> [image]

How can I set this option in my profile picture?

Comment: It isn't an option. It is the [established user](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) privilege. When you hit 1000 reputation you will get it.

Comment: You can't.  Why would you want to?

Answer (score 4):

It's not an option. The expended card is a privilege you get as an [Established User](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) once you reach 1000 reputation.